# stop the timer created and save the time

Tags: javascript

I have created a timer with the moment.js as below:

```
    var event = moment().add(15, 'minutes');

    var x = setInterval(function (){
        var now = moment();
            var timeleft = event - now;

            var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000*60*60))/(1000*60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000*60))/1000);

            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =''+minutes+'     '+seconds;
    },1000);
```

I want to stop the timer on page unload and save the time to DB 
Once the user comes back on the page they want to resume the timer from where it was paused.

Any suggestions on the above as I am new to javascript

Comment: Have you tried using cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already there, first lets make your function generic and expose interface functions to start and stop timer.

```
var timer = null;
var timeleft = null;

function startTimer(threshold) {

    stopTimer();

    var event = moment().add(threshold, 'minutes');
    timer = setInterval(function (){
        var now = moment();
        timeleft = event - now;

        var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000*60*60))/(1000*60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000*60))/1000);

        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =''+minutes+'     '+seconds;
    }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
    if(timer !== null) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        saveTime(timeLeft); //save this time to storage
        timeLeft = null;
    }   
}
```

Now we just need to bind those functions to window events, for example if you want to stop the timer when user switches the tab,

```
window.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
    stopTimer()
}, false);
```

Similarly you can start the timer when user switches back to the tab

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function( event ) {
   // get the last saved timeLeft and pass it to startTimer
   // Note you can store the timeLeft in either cookie or database
   startTimer(timeLeft)
}, false);
```

**Warning** The code is not tested

**Update 1:** We need `stopTimer` function in `startTimer` because we want to clear the previous `setInterval` function, if we don't then `setInterval's` callback will trigger for every time we register it. You can actually see that behavior if you remove the `stopTimer` from `startTimer`. We also need to reset the `timeLeft` which had already saved.

`threshold` is the initial time of timer, so for the first time it will be the total time which we want to allow and then if user's switch tab we will manually update it to get the remaining time

Comment: I guess we need to use focus in the last function where we initiate startTimer(timeLeft).Please comfirm

Comment: I have integrated the code and its working to some extent. Could you please let me know why have we stopTimer function in startTimer and what would be the threshold value Thank you

Comment: I am getting  confused in passing the threshold value. if we wish to pass 15 minutes + current time so what would be threshold value and the format which we need to pass

Answer (score 0):

This is  the code

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) 
    {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";";
        console.log(cvalue);
    }             
    var x = null; 

    var timeleft= null;



    function startTimer(30)
    {
        stopTimer();

        var event = moment().add(30, 'seconds');

        x = setInterval(function ()
        {
            var now = moment();
            timeleft = event - now;
            var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000*60))/1000);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =''+minutes+'     '+seconds;

            if(timeleft<1000)
            {
                clearInterval(x);
                window.alert('Your time has been expired');    
            }            
        },1000);
    }
    window.addEventListener("blur", function(event)
    {
        stopTimer();
    },false);

    window.addEventListener("focus", function(event)
    {
        console.log(getCookie("timeleft"));
        startTimer(timeleft);
    },false)

    function stopTimer()
    {
        if(x !== null)
        {
            clearInterval(x);
            setCookie("timeleft",timeleft,1);
            timeleft=null;
        }
    }

    function getCookie(cname) 
    {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
        {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
            {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
            {
                return valueOf(c);
            }
        }
        return "null";
    }
```

`

this is wat i am trying to implement as per your answer sir 
also please check  the comment
assist on this please
thank you